# Problem with logo and nav menu overlapping on zoom

Tags: css, html, overlap

The menu itself has a couple of issues I don't know how to fix, Code seems valid (at least in that part), but the problem is that when an user enters the website, and it's zoomed (as in the case of netbooks), the website logo and the nav1 menu overlap. Any clues on what's failing here? I have tried in firefox, chrome and Opera on my computer and it's not overlapping, but on different computers is... Cache issues for that bit.

Any help will be more than welcomed!

this is the [URL](http://roadseguridad.com.ar/wp_files/)

Comment: You need to remove the part about "netbooks" from your question - it makes your question more unclear. There is nothing magical about browsers on netbooks - they simply have less screen space to work with. Reducing the width of your browser window to, say `1024px` is like using a netbook.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the resolution or browser width of the netbooks is too small to accommodate both the logo and the nav.  I see the same issue when I drag my browser to be more narrow.

You can either shrink the logo or change the width of `#header` to 1024px to prevent it from shrinking too much.

However, this would mean content would spill out of the browser window on the netbooks.

I recommend shrinking the logo if you want to keep the 964px width of `#header`

Comment: thanks for the tip. Do you see the quote under the nav awkward?

Comment: It looks fine here.  The width of the header shouldn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

your logo is absolutely positioned so it will always be 87px from left 
may be you need to write the css  in a different way

```
.logo img {
left: 87px;
padding: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 28px;
z-index: 18;
}
```

Comment: I tried fixing it with position: relative; but theres a big gap between the nav and the slider then